# Unlink by inode in C?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I'm writing an application for a cheap-ass embedded linux system whose yaffs2 filesystem often corrupts (crappy nand), often yielding filesystem errors such as temporary files with broken names. These filenames may end up with slashes and/or unprintable characters. `unlink()` by filename (as given by `readdir()` fails with "no such file or directory", which is understandable. Question is: Is there a way to unlink the files by inode num instead of by filename, to workaround this?

I know there are `find` tricks to do similar things, but I need this done without a dependency on system utilities, in other words in pure C/Cpp. Can't do much about hardware or kernel and I definitely can't format the partition every time this happens.

Comment: When you think you cannot savely delete a file by name, I am a bit at a loss on how you want to be able to safely obtain an inode # and safely delete the file by node # - If a file system is corrupt, it is corrupt. "Crappy NAND" doesn't normally make a difference between names and other fs info.